# Script that converts html tables to CSV (preferably python)

Tags: python, html, html-table, export-to-csv

I have a large number of html tables that I'd like to convert into CSV. Pasting individual tables into excel and saving them as .csv works, as does pasting the html tables into simple online converters. But I have thousands of individual tables, so I need a script that can automate the conversion process.

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions as to how I could go about doing this? Python is the only language I have a decent knowledge of, so some sort of python script would be ideal. I've searched for similar questions, but all the python examples I've found are quite complicated to me, and go beyond my basic level of understanding.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's a rather broad question you're asking there - you want a Python program that [parses HTML](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html), extracts any data contained within `<table>` elements, and [saves the result as a CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). I'd suggest that you go away and try writing something based on the links I've provided here first, and come back to Stack Overflow if you have any problems with **specific** parts of the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pandas`.  It has a function to read html tables into a data structure, and then a function that will write that data structure to a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://myurl.com/mypage/'

for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_html(url)):
    df.to_csv('myfile_%s.csv' % i)
```

Note that since an html page may have more than one table, the function to get the table always returns a list of tables (even if there is only one table).  That is why I use a loop here.

Comment: Awesome script. I didn't know about this - added to my #protips

Comment: I've had a play around with this, and I think it will be perfect for my needs. Thank you!